# Gremlin - search for vertex by properties of property

Tags: gremlin

I have a vertex that has nested properties under a specific property. Example:

```
  {
    "id": "X",
    "label": "deployment",
    "type": "vertex",
    "properties": {
      "name": [
        {
          "id": "X",
          "value": "myvalue1"
        }
      ],
      "labels": [
        {
          "id": "xxxxx",
          "value": "my-labels",
          "properties": {
            "key": "value"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

**My problem is:** I would like to search for a sub-property with a specific value. How would I construct the query to find vertices with that value? I can't seem to find any documentation on trying to find that sub-property.

Plenty of documentation on finding and sorting on a property of a vertex, but not this.

The goal of doing this, is that there are many "labels" under my labels and I want to eventually create edges among vertices with matching sub labels.

Answer (score 1):

This will be a scan over all vertices, so be warned that it's not going to be a high-performance query.

```
g.V().filter(properties("my-labels").has("key", "value"))
```

To give you an example over [The Crew](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#the-crew-toy-graph) graph:

```
//
// Where did TinkerPop crew members move in and after 2005?
//
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createTheCrew().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:14], standard]
gremlin> g.V().filter(properties("location").has("startTime", gte(2005))).
           project("name","locations").
             by("name").
             by(properties("location").has("startTime", gte(2005)).value().fold())
==>[name:marko,locations:[santa fe]]
==>[name:stephen,locations:[purcellville]]
==>[name:matthias,locations:[baltimore,oakland,seattle]]
==>[name:daniel,locations:[kaiserslautern,aachen]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the example that is really useful. To continue off of your example, I want to add an edge to any vertex that has the same sub property as another label, not a hard coded string I'm looking for. In this example:
```
g.V().hasLabel("label1").as("a").
  V().hasLabel("label2").as("b").
  where("a", eq("b")).by("key").
  addE("link").from("a").to("b")
```
how would I construct a traversal to do it more programatically, instead of the "label1", and "label2" in that example? I can use your example to get the filter properties, but wondering on this piece.

Comment: I'm basically at the point of wondering do I handle adding the edges in my python code, and then send in the concatenated string, or can I handle this in a gremlin query without needing to write more python code as well......

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "doing `label1` and `label2` more programmatically" or rather how this is related to your initial question. If this has nothing to do with the previous question, then please open a new question.